# mvc HTTP 404 error

Tags: mvc, asp.net-core, controller

Boas,

Criei um projecto ASP:NET WEB Core 2.0 Appl.

Criei views e controllers.

Quando faço um submit via:

```
<form asp-controller="Audit" asp-action="Search" method="post">
```

Em vez de abrir via (controller Audit, IAction, search, return View()) 
a página/view Audit em

`http://localhost:62857/Home/Audit`

tenta abrir (com erro)

`http://localhost:62857/Audit/Search`.

O mesmo repete-se para outras views.

O que estou a fazer mal?

**NOTA1**: Nao tenho experiencia suficiente (ainda) para usar routes e maps.

**NOTA2**: Se uso o eturn Content("AOC") visualizo o AOC.

'Audit.cshtml'
form asp-controller="Audit" asp-action="Search" method="post"> div class="row">input type="search" id="inputSearch" name="inputSearch">input type="Submit" value="Search...">/div>/form

AuditController
Public IActionResult Search(string inputSearch)
        {
            ViewBag.Search = inputSearch;

```
        // return View("Index");
        // return View();
        // return Content("test audit");
        return View("~/Views/Home/Audit");
    }
```

Obrigado pela atenção

Comment: Não entendi muito bem sua duvida, você está tedo problemas  em  encontrar o  caminho  espeficio ? ou o formulario  está fazendo  o  submit para o Controller/Action Errado ? Poderia postar o codigo de seu controller

Comment: Pelo que eu entendi, está correto, pois se você usa o ASP-CONTROLLER="Audit" quer dizer que vai buscar o controller audit. Se você quer que busque o controller Home, troque para ASP-CONTROLLER="Home"